# Is there anyway to bring up the color picker in VSCode when writing JS/JSX files?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx, color-picker

When using React, it would be nice to be able to have access to a color picker with hex code when using inline styling. Any extensions or settings out there to remedy this?

Comment: What I have seen with vscode is color code auto complete when working with css files.

Comment: I use strictly inline styles in my React applications, but I still keep a CSS file with a .testColor{ color:#ffffff; } class in it in all of my projects.  It's not as convenient as having the ability to visually edit colors in JSX, but it works very well for keeping you in your project when you do want to experiment with colors for eventual use in a JSX file.

Comment: @hawkeyegold not the answer I was hoping for but that seems like a pretty good workaround. Thanks!

Comment: This related issue might of interest: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/52364

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76066924/836330 for native functionality coming to vscode.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ran into this problem myself, so I built [Color Pick](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adam-watters.vscode-color-pick).

Answer (score 1):

I've created [an extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dae.vscode-mac-color-picker) that uses macOS native color picker, and it works well with inline styles and any file formats, as long as the selected color is in a CSS compliant notation (hex, rgba(...) etc)