# Unable to view Hex color code selection box

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, expo

Hello everyone I am using VS code editor in Windows 10 while setting colors for background or for any specific styling purpose unable to view Hex code viewer which makes a easy task in selecting hex code as below:

[image: for reference see attached]

have tried installing Hex editor in VS code extension but no luck.

your response may resolve my issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there anyway to bring up the color picker in VSCode when writing JS/JSX files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48655877/is-there-anyway-to-bring-up-the-color-picker-in-vscode-when-writing-js-jsx-files)

Comment: It is still unsolved. thanks for your response, Ricky.