# how to bring the vscode css color picker feature into js file with string that match color name format?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, color-picker

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/css

None of the current plugin able to do so. I am really surprised. even intellij has this support!

Also the reply from vscode itself is a bit not helpful either.
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/36485

Any hint on how to build such plugin, seems shouldn't be really hard since its really just porting the feature from one file extension to another?

Anyone able to resolve this?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

I found [colorize](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kamikillerto.vscode-colorize) which can highlight *JavaScript* and *TypeScript* (among others) [GitHub](https://github.com/KamiKillertO/vscode-colorize)

In your `settings.json` in *VSCode* just add languages you'd like to target:

```
"colorize.languages": ["typescript", "javascript", "css", "scss"]
```

[image]

Comment: got it working with `"colorize.include": ["**/*.coffee"]`

Comment: Does this extension have a color picker? Or does it just highlight colors? I installed it but there is no color picker in jsx

Comment: @AliMertCakar unfortunately "Colorize" doesn't include a colour _picker_, it only highlights known colour strings.. I've just switched from that to "JSON Color Token". if you haven't already done so in the almost-2-years since you posted this comment, I'd highly recommend you check it out... :)

Comment: @AndreGreeff I've checked and I am using "Color Highlight". Works in .tsx files for me. I don't even remember myself commenting on this :)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question which is referring to the color ``picker`` and not just a color ``highlight``

Comment: for those wanting .tsx files include "typescriptreact"

Answer (score 38):

Updating for this question. Seems like:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AntiAntiSepticeye.vscode-color-picker

adds color picker brings functionality into other languages.

Personally tested and works in typescript. It's relatively new so it doesn't have a lot of downloads or installs but it works as advertised.

Comment: This works great! Thanks! This should definitely be the new correct answer, because it adds the same color functionality from css files into any other file type. (python, js, etc.)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: This isn't worked for me :c

Comment: @ezequiel-guitler Make sure to add the language you're using into settings.json, like so: `"vscode-color-picker.languages": ["python", "javascript", "typescript", "typescriptreact"]`

Answer (score 32):

To anyone who uses [Colorize](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kamikillerto.vscode-colorize) and wants it to work on their React project (CSS in JS and such) use:

```
"colorize.languages": ["javascriptreact", "javascript", "css", "scss"]
```

as apparently "javascriptreact" is needed and not "javascript"

For TypeScript in React use  "typescriptreact".

Comment: Thanks for giving the right information to highlight colors in typescript!!

Answer (score 20):

The ability to see a color decorator in front of css-stle color formats or invoke a standalone color picker anywhere is currently in vscode Insiders v1.78.

Demo in ts and jsx files:

[image: setting toggle and color decorators]

Setting: `Editor: Default Color Decorators`

Command: `Show or Focus Standalone Color Picker`

See more at https://stackoverflow.com/a/76066924/836330

Comment: Here is the answer! Why to install extensions. But i observed, it works in tsx only when there is StyleSheet object imported, either blank or with styles. const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

Comment: I have a weird behaviour, not sure whether this is bc of some other extension I have. But activating this and then reloading the window I do see the previews in my tailwind.config.js for a couple of seconds, then they disappear so I'm on the hunt on why that happens

Comment: update: found out it is the Talwind CSS Intellisense extension so I'll probably open an issue

Answer (score 13):

VS extension [JSON color token](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yechunan.json-color-token) is capable of bringing up the native color picker in any language.

To make this work with JS and React, add this in VS Code's settings.json:

```
"jsonColorToken.languages": [
    "json",
    "jsonc",
    "javascript",
    "javascriptreact"
  ]
```

Source: https://github.com/YECHUNAN/json-color-token/issues/2#issuecomment-977261832

Comment: I've been using Colorize (as per many other answers) for ages now, but thanks to your answer here now, I've just switched over to JSON Color Token instead... this is so much nicer to use, thank you! :)

Comment: Thanks - after installing the extension, updating settings.json, and _restarting_ VSCode, it's looking good!

Comment: It works but only with Hex codes, not RGB.

Answer (score 1):

There is one possible implementation with `vscode-color-info` from [wayncheng](https://github.com/mattbierner/vscode-color-info/issues/15#issuecomment-403567314)

Adding the following code to colorInfo.languages in settings.json should do the trick. Make sure to include all the default languages as well so they aren't disabled.

```
{
    "selector": "javascript",
    "colors": "css"
}
```

So your settings.json should look something like this:

```
"colorInfo.languages": [
    {
        "selector": "css",
        "colors": "css"
    },
    {
        "selector": "sass",
        "colors": "css"
    },
    {
        "selector": "scss",
        "colors": "css"
    },
    {
        "selector": "less",
        "colors": "css"
    },
    {
        "selector": "html",
        "colors": "css"
    },
    {
        "selector": "javascript",
        "colors": "css"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

It works to use `"colorize.include": ["**/*.js"]` in my create-react-app project

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem that TSX (TypeScript files with XML) wouldn't properly highlight the color. The solution was to add "typescriptreact" to the array as described in the post by @rouan.

PS @Ali Mert Cakar it adds no color picker and only highlights the color in the respective color.