# Is there a way to get color previews in VSCode for tailwind.config.js?

Tags: visual-studio-code, tailwind-css

[image: tailwind.config.js file]

I have some custom colors defined, VSCode does not show color previews and I have to manually check to remember which one to use, even with color naming. Are there any settings/extensions that allow me to preview the HSL colors defined in the values?

Answer (score 0):

I found the extension called Color Highlight. https://github.com/enyancc/vscode-ext-color-highlight

Answer (score 0):

Since vscode v1.78 you can do this (note that is in a `js` file):

[image]

Make sure these two settings are enabled:

```
Editor: Color Decorators
Editor: Default Color Decorators
```

That second setting means that non-css type files, like `javascript`, will also get a color decorator.  An extension could specifically provide a `ColorDecorator` or if not use the default color decorator (i.e., the one that provides a color decorator for css-type files.

Comment: (I might be missing something, in which case I apologize) why didn't you dupe vote to https://stackoverflow.com/a/76067075/11107541 ?

Comment: the `ColorDecorator` is missing on the API Ref doc page