# How do you display the VSCode color picker in JSON regardless of the key?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, jsonschema

I am developing a theme and want all the HEX colors to display the VSCode color picker next to them.

Someone had asked a [similar question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60160718/vs-code-built-in-color-picker-feature-doesnt-work-in-json-files), but I wasn't sure how to implement it even  after looking at [the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json#_json-schemas-and-settings).

So I tried creating a JSON schema after [this example here (Github)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/34663).

I got the following code to work sort-of, but it only works if the JSON `key` string has the name of `hex-color`:

```json
...
"type": "object",
"properties": {
    "hex-color": {"type": "string","format": "color"}
}
...
```

so

```json
{
    "test": "#000", // Does not work
    "hex-color": "#000" // Works
}
```

When creating a VSCode theme, it's very difficult and time consuming to name every property key possible in a theme file for a schema. Is there a way to create a wildcard key, or a better way to detect if a value is a hex color?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I enable the VS Code Color Picker outside of CSS-like scopes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50622898/how-can-i-enable-the-vs-code-color-picker-outside-of-css-like-scopes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I resolved my issue with the color picker not showing up in VSCode theme JSON files. (*This solution may not work completely with other JSON files.*)

Add the following line to your theme:

```json
"$schema": "vscode://schemas/color-theme",
```

This sets the file's schema to the VSCode's color theme schema, which has most if not all schemas to show the color picker on HEX colors. After some more research, I found [the following repo (Github)](https://github.com/wraith13/vscode-schemas) where @wraith13 has uploaded  VSCode's JSON schemas.

The `color-theme` schema can be found [here (v1.58.2)](https://github.com/wraith13/vscode-schemas/blob/master/en/v1.58.2/schemas/color-theme.json).