# VScode doesnt show square with color using Tailwind

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, colors, tailwind-css, vscode-extensions

Hi **what is the extension** that does it:

[image]

I need these squares with colors, but my code is:

[image]

I can see square colors while I write, but after I write it doesn't show any square colors as you see

Comment: 1) possible dup of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76182741/11107541)

Comment: 2) Are you using any tailwind extensions in VS Code? If so, what version exactly? And does this problem occur in older versions of the extension? (You can try older versions by right clicking the gear icon for the extension in the extension list and selecting the "Install Another Version..." option. Try doing a "binary search" through the versions for each of those two extensions and see if you can get back the behaviour you want. If so, then it might be a regression, which you should then report to the maintainers or ask them if it's by-design and not a regression.)

Comment: possibly related issue that is supposedly fixed in version 0.9.8 of the Tailwind CSS extensions: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-intellisense/issues/728. another issue supposedly fixed in 0.9.11: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-intellisense/issues/750

Comment: Are you on VS Code 1.78? If so, does this issue still happen if you revert to VS Code 1.77?

Comment: Also sounds related: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-intellisense/issues/777

Comment: @user I'm using tailwind extension v0.9.11 and VSCode 1.78. How I do downgrade to 1.77?

Comment: google "vscode downgrade version". top result: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49346733/11107541