# How can I have an interactive view of the color names on R in the vscode interface?

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, colors

I have a very nice view of the color that I can change interactively on my vscode interface. However I don't know how I get this function to install it again on a new computer. You can see my screenshot to show what I mean. When I click on the blue square for instance I have the interactive palette which open and I can choose the color that I want which directly change the name of the color.

Thank you in advance.
[image]

Comment: this is the buildin color picker, you need an extension that adds the right decorator to the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No extension needed anymore, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/76066924/836330.

Enable this setting: `Editor: Default Color Decorators`

and the little square color decorator should show up in your `r` code.

[image]